# Achar div irmã anterior no CSS

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<div class="load">
    <img src="images/load.svg" class="loadimg">
</div>

<div class="tela carregando">
    <span>Teste</span>
</div>
```

o seguinte css:

```
.carregando {
    display: none;
}

.load {
    display: none;
}

.load > .carregando {
    display: block;
}
```

e o JS:

```
$(".loadimg).click(function(){
    $('.tela').removeClass('carregando');
});
```

Quero que quando remover a `class` carregando o CSS mude o estilo pra algo do tipo:

```
.load > .carregando {
    display: block;
}
```

Se a classe `carregando` tiver ativa a classe `load` é display block... nesse ultimo CSS de exemplo tentei usando `>` mas não deu certo...

Tem que ser em CSS em jQuery eu sei fazer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta estilizar o CSS assim:

```js
$(".loading").click(function(){
    $('.tela').removeClass('carregando');
});
```

```css
.carregando {
    display: none;
}

.load {
    display: none;
}

.carregando ~ .load {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tela carregando">
    <span>Teste</span>
</div>

<div class="load">
    <img src="images/load.svg" class="loadimg">
</div>

<button class='loading'>TESTE</button>
```

Como isso se chama [Sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) tive que mudar a ordem dos elementos.

Comment: vlw!"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!